# Cannot Diagnose Neo4j REST API Inquiry Failure

Tags: scala, rest, neo4j

I'm messing with some code in Scala (2.9.2) to query a neo4j (2.2.0) server using REST API via Jersey (1.19) and Cypher.  My first transaction succeeds (HTTP 200) returning some nice XHTML.  The second more involved transaction containing a valid Cypher query returns 405 with no data or message.  It causes a stack dump in the server log.  The same query succeeds via the console to the same server.  I don't know how to proceed to diagnose the problem.  Details follow:

Here is the transaction and result via Cypher console:

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ match (p)-[r]->(n) where n.number = '15' return p,r,n;
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| p                                        | r                                     | n                       |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Node[1451]{name:"Elizabeth Maher Muoio"} | :REPRESENTS[1725]{inHouse:"Assembly"} | Node[1381]{number:"15"} |
| Node[1450]{name:"Reed Gusciora"}         | :REPRESENTS[1724]{inHouse:"Assembly"} | Node[1381]{number:"15"} |
| Node[1449]{name:"Shirley K. Turner"}     | :REPRESENTS[1723]{inHouse:"Senate"}   | Node[1381]{number:"15"} |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
3 rows
24 ms
```

Here is the Scala snippet:

```
val n4url = "http://dev.cosi.com:7474/db/data/"

// Make a client...
val c = Client.create // Uses jersey 1.19
//val cl = c.getClass.getName;     println("cl: "+cl);
c.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter("neo4j","connected"))

// Dumb test of comms w server...
val resource = c.resource(n4url)
val response = resource.get(classOf[ClientResponse])
printf("\nGET on [%s], status code [%d]\n%s\n",n4url,response.getStatus(),
  response.getEntity(classOf[String]))
response.close

println("\n=== MOVING ALONG TO REAL INQUIRY ===")
val inq = n4url+"transaction/commit"
val res2 = c.resource(inq)
val query = "match (p)-[r]->(n) where n.number = '15' return p,r,n"
val payload = "{\"statements\" : [ {\"statement\" : \"" + query + "\"} ]}";
val resp2 = resource.
  accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).
  `type`(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).
  entity(payload).
  post(classOf[ClientResponse])
printf("POST [%s] to [%s], status code [%d], returned data: " +
  System.getProperty("line.separator") + "%s\n",
  payload,inq,resp2.getStatus,resp2.getEntity(classOf[String]))
resp2.close
```

Here is the output of the Scala program:

```
    GET on [http://dev.cosi.com:7474/db/data/], status code [200]
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html><head><title>Root</title><meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<link href='http://resthtml.neo4j.org/style/rest.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/webadmin/htmlbrowse.js'></script>
</head>
<body onload='javascript:neo4jHtmlBrowse.start();' id='root'>
<div id='content'><div id='header'><h1><a title='Neo4j REST interface' href='/'><span>Neo4j REST interface</span></a></h1></div>
<div id='page-body'>
<table class="root"><caption>Root</caption>
<tr class='odd'><th>relationship_index</th><td><a href="http://dev.cosi.com:7474/db/data/index/relationship">http://dev.cosi.com:7474/db/data/index/relationship</a></td></tr>
<tr><th>node_index</th><td><a href="http://dev.cosi.com:7474/db/data/index/node">http://dev.cosi.com:7474/db/data/index/node</a></td></tr>
</table>
<div class='break'>&nbsp;</div></div></div></body></html>

=== MOVING ALONG TO REAL INQUIRY ===
POST [{"statements" : [ {"statement" : "match (p)-[r]->(n) where n.number = '15' return p,r,n"} ]}] to [http://dev.cosi.com:7474/db/data/transaction/commit], status code [405], returned data:
```

Here is the server log fragment:

```
   FINE: Mapped exception to response: 405
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.TerminatingRule.accept(TerminatingRule.java:66)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:540)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:715)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:800)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
        at org.neo4j.server.rest.dbms.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:120)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1125)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1059)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:52)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:248)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:620)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:540)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: also your query should include a label for `n` and you should have an index on `:Label(number)`

Comment: Well, it's just for experimentation and it did achieve the desired result, but I appreciate your answer.  Is that for performance reasons, or are there other considerations?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I referenced the wrong ClientResponse object in the second inquiry.  Fixed by changing:

```
val resp2 = resource.
```

to

```
val resp2 = res2.
```

Comment: So, basically just a bone-headed oversight.  But still, I wonder why that would cause a stack dump in the server, and how I could have gotten some clues to the problem aside from just staring at the code.